# Open browser only if page not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I need to shell out to a browser application.  I am using the Process.Start({url}) method to do this.

However, if the url is already displayed in the browser, I do not want to open another browser window or tab; I want to navigate to the browser/tab already open.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: yes you can try something like this NickV `string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: This is a WPF application.  I do not have an HttpContext.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have using System.Web in your using at the top of your .cs file.. ?

Comment: This is not a good idea. It breaks expected UI functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the open IE windows using the following method:

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

string filename;

foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
{
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();

    if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
    {
        try
        {
            Uri test = new Uri(ie.LocationURL);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to the SHDocVw COM component.

Also, if you're using a browser other than IE this won't work.

An alternative would be to use something like GeckoFX https://bitbucket.org/geckofx or a separate winform app with a WebBrowser control instead of using Process.Start